# Centre index.php page

Tags: php

When coding a web application, should all files be linked through a single index.php file.
Would doing such a thing help security, or would it make more complications later on.

How would you guys achieve this? Most (if no all) the site I have seen use this approach. Is there a reason for this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit? It is hard to know what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing so doesn't such much about security.

The main advantage is that having every request go through `index.php` makes sure that you have a single entry point into your applications's PHP code -- which means you can put your initialization / configuration code there *(or call it from there)* and it'll always get executed.

On the how to achieve this, you'll need :

- A `RewriteRule` so all requests to non-existant files are sent to `index.php`
- In your `index.php` script *(or somewhere called by `index.php`, like a router)*, put some code to call the right controller/action.

For the `RewriteRule`, here's for example what is often done with [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html) :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: If you don't use a central index.php, how else would you link files together?

Comment: Not sure I quite understand your question : using several .php scripts *(one per actual page of the website)* has been done for many years, and does work quite well *(with its advantages and drawbacks)*